# How to extract specific part of column using REGEXP in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table plan and it has following data stored as:

```
NAME                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)=b.acc_num                  
EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where a.group_id=b.acc_num
```

I want to extract the part after **where** to **=**.My expected output is:

```
 NAME                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)                  
a.group_id
```

So,I tried like this::

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'^[EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where]',1,6) from ot.plan;
```

But its not working.Is it possible to extract such part in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` and `instr` as following:

> ```
> SQL> with your_Data as
>   2  (select 'EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)=b.acc_num' as str from dual)
>   3  SELECT SUBSTR(STR, INSTR(STR, 'where') + 5, INSTR(STR, '=') -(INSTR(STR, 'where') + 5))
>   4  FROM YOUR_DATA;
>
> SUBSTR(STR,INSTR(STR,'WH
> ------------------------
>  SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (slow) regular expressions and can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( name, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos ) AS match
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         INSTR( LOWER(name), ' where ' ) + LENGTH( ' where ') AS start_pos,
         INSTR( name, '=', INSTR( LOWER(name), ' where ' ) ) AS end_pos
  FROM   table_name
)
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( NAME ) AS
SELECT 'EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)=b.acc_num' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EXISTS(SELECT 1 from a where a.group_id=b.acc_num' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | MATCH                   |
> | :---------------------- |
> | SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4) |
> | a.group_id              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=620b24b467d1317c22205c8a70d2f952)*

Comment: what does  select INSTR( LOWER(name), '=',23 ) from ot.plan; do?

Comment: @Randomguy `INSTR` finds the position of the next `=` character in the `name` column and skips the first 22 characters and starts looking from the 23rd. But you could also have found that out by searching for the [`INSTR` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html#GUID-47E3A7C4-ED72-458D-A1FA-25A9AD3BE113)